# Javascript: If-sentence logic, What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

My current solution does not calculate the added ship cost. My condition isn't working, I've been able to do similar problems with functions but I would like to know where I went wrong here.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
var numOrdered = 0;
var priceItem = 0;
var shipCost = 0;
var amtDue = 0;
numOrdered = prompt("Enter the number ordered ",0);
priceItem = prompt("Enter the price of the item ",0);
amtDue = numOrdered * priceItem;
if (amtDue > 1000)
   {
    shipCost = 0;
   }
else
   {
    shipCost = amtDue * .1;
   }
amtDue = amtDue + shipCost;
document.write("You owe ", amtDue);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: This looks fine to me. What undesired output are you getting, and for what input?

Comment: Could you come up with a better title?

Comment: I've made some modifications and made a jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Pg3wU/2/

It seems to work fine there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me. I put your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/XVzKb/

No changes -- if I enter 5 and then when prompted again 10 the total displayed in the page is 55 which is 5 * 10 * 1.1 = 55. Note that if your input includes a non-numeric character like `$` or `,` then you'll need to parse it like so:

```
number = parseInt(response.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''), 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check out the developer tools in Chrome or Firefox and use console.log or put in some break points to help you understand what is working and what is not.  This way you can see if its your javascript or your html document that is failing.

That being said, you are comparing strings not numbers, so you'll want to use parseInt on the values you are getting back from the prompt.

```
priceItem = parseInt(priceItem, 10);
```